# Is it possible to install SQL Server 2005 (enterprise edition) on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008, enterprise

Is it possible to install SQL Server 2005 (Enterprise Edition) on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-on-windows-server-2008/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why shouldn't it be possible to do that???

Just do it! I don't see any reasons why you should have any issues with this setup.

Go ahead and try it - if you run into any actual problems, come back (but preferably to http://Serverfault.com) and ask for help.

Comment: Hm... Lets by licenses for thousands of dollars and just try if it works... doesn't sound like a good idea. I would also try to find out if they are compatible beforehand.

Comment: @Guffa: One would assume that they know what they want when they specifically mention Enterprise edition. Also, they could try Developer edition which is EE but for non-prod use

Comment: @Guffa: from the question, I assumes he already has the licenses.... just wants to know whether he can install on Win2008, or whether he needs to use a Win2003/2003R2 box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The SQL Server version doesn't have to match the operating system version, as it is for example with the IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[What does the MS site for SQL Server 2005 say?](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/system-requirements.aspx) (my bold)

> SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008
>   and Windows Vista
>
> In an effort to provide customers with
>   more secure products, Microsoft
>   **Windows Server 2008** and Microsoft
>   Windows Vista are supported by **SQL
>   Server 2005 Express Edition Service
>   Pack 1 (SP1)**, and for all other
>   editions will be supported by **SQL
>   Server 2005 Service Pack 2 (SP2)** or
>   later when it becomes available.
>   Earlier versions of SQL Server,
>   including SQL Server 2000 (all
>   editions including Desktop Engine
>   edition, a.k.a MSDE), SQL Server 7.0,
>   and SQL Server 6.5, will not be
>   supported on Windows Server 2008 or
>   Windows Vista.